# Directive binding undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a bit new to angularjs. I'm writing a directive but I can't understand how bindToController runs. I read this helpful article http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html but I can't understand why in the following example I have undefined.

```
.directive('firstDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        bindToController: {
            directiveInput:'='
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/directive-tree/directive-tree.html',
        controllerAs: 'directiveTreeCtrl',
        controller: function($scope, $uibModal){
            var self = this;
            self.selected = null;
            console.log(self.directiveInput); //HERE IS THE UNDEFINED
            $scope.modalOptions = {
                windowClass: 'semi-modal',
            }

            this.openDirectiveModal = function(object, index) {
                //Other irrelevant code
            }
        }
    } 
 });
```

After that I can use the input for the HTML template without any problem.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="object in directiveTreeCtrl.directiveInput">
        {{object.Id}}&emsp;{{object.Name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Why in the HTML template can I use directiveInput and it's instantiated with the correct values and my console.log show me "undefined"?

Maybe it's a silly question. Thank you

Comment: You need to  use your directive like this ´<first-directive></first-directive>´ in  your html. The [official angular directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is more complete

Comment: @TomShen I'm using it correctly. The only doubt that I have is why I get an undefined in that console.log() and I can use that object after in my html when I render it

Answer (score 1):

Typically the code I write to achieve this looks like so:

```
.directive('firstDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            directiveInput:'='
        },
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'components/directive-tree/directive-tree.html',
        controllerAs: 'directiveTreeCtrl',
        controller: function($scope, $uibModal){
            var self = this;
            self.selected = null;
            console.log(self.directiveInput); //HERE IS THE UNDEFINED
            $scope.modalOptions = {
                windowClass: 'semi-modal',
            }

            this.openDirectiveModal = function(object, index) {
                //Other irrelevant code
            }
        }
    } 
 });
```

Now the HTML

```
<first-directive directive-input="inputObject"></first-directive>
```

Comment: I don't have any doubt about how to use it. My question is another. Why the console.log is printing UNDEFINED and after that the HTML is rendering correctly the object.